# Convertir una fracción a número mixto javascript

Tags: javascript, algoritmos, matemáticas

El objetivo de la función es convertir de fracción a número mixto. Hasta el momento puedo obtener la parte entera pero tengo problemas al simplificar el dividendo y el divisor del numero (por ejemplo de `6/9` a `2/3`). Gracias

```js
function convertirFraccion(s) {
    s = s.split('/').map(a => Number(a))
    let modulo = s[0] % s[1]
    let resto = modulo / s[1]
    let numeral = Math.floor(s[0] / s[1])
    return modulo == 0 ? numeral : `${numeral} ${modulo}/${s[1]}`
}

console.log(convertirFraccion('24/9'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El código que tienes funciona muy bien, solo tienes un problema al hacer la simplificación del dividendo y el divisor.

En la simplificación debes reducir ambos números dividiéndolos por sus factores primos hasta que ambos sean primos entre si (que no tengan ningún factor primo en común).

Para esto en tu código verificas el resultado de `modulo`, de ser 0 implica que la división es exacta y solo se muestra un resultado entero.

De no ser así deberás descomponer los números, para eso comienzas comprobando el modulo de ambos números empezando por el 2 hasta la mitad del dividendo, (podría ser mas optimo con la raíz cuadrada ya que el numero mas grande que puede dividir exactamente a un numero es menor o igual a su raíz cuadrada).

Cada vez que ambos módulos resulten en 0, divides el numero sobre el factor actual. Luego se va incrementando dicho factor.

Al final para mostrar el numero mixto puedes verificar si la parte entera es mayor a 0, de no ser así no hay necesidad de mostrarla.

```
return `${numeral > 0 ? numeral+' ' : ''}${modulo}/${s[1]}`
```

El código queda de la siguiente forma:

```js
function convertirFraccion(s) {
    s = s.split('/').map(a => Number(a))
    let modulo = s[0] % s[1]
    let resto = modulo / s[1]
    let numeral = Math.floor(s[0] / s[1])
    
    if(modulo!=0){
      act=2;
      while(act<s[1]/2){
        if(modulo%act==0 && s[1]%act==0){
          modulo/=act; 
          s[1]/=act;
        }
        act++;
      }
      return `${numeral > 0 ? numeral+' ' : ''}${modulo}/${s[1]}`
    }
    else
      return numeral
}
//ejemplos
console.log(convertirFraccion('24/9'));
console.log(convertirFraccion('4/3'));
console.log(convertirFraccion('28/7'));
console.log(convertirFraccion('2/36'));
console.log(convertirFraccion('53/83'));
```

Esta es solo una forma en bruto de resolverlo ,considero que puede optimizarse un poco mas, saludos.

Comment: gracias amigo.. siempre estas por ahi eres un crack

Comment: lo unico es que no simplifica varias veces por el mismo numero.. si tienes por ejemplo 12/24 regresara 2/4..  si en la parte donde pones la condicion `if(modulo%act==0 && s[1]%act==0){
          modulo/=act; 
          s[1]/=act;` agregas `act=1` para q con los proximos numeros compruebe si son simplificables por uno q ya comprabastes como 2

Comment: @IsraelGonzález es cierto, un factor primo puede repetirse gracias por la acotación.

Answer (score 1):

El problema no estaba pensado en el caso de que insertaran alguno de los numeros negativos o ambos.. cosa que complica un poco las cosas  dejo por aqui esta funcion... a fuerza bruta pero que comprueba todos los casos

```js
function convertirFraccion(s) {
    s = s.split('/').map(a => +a)
    const division = s[0] / s[1]
    let modulo = s[0] % s[1]
    if (s[1] == 0) {
    throw new Error('ZeroDivisionError')
    }
    if (modulo == 0) {
        return `` + s[0] / s[1]
    } else if (division < 1 && division > -1) {
        let sinNumeral = simplificarFraccion(s[0], s[1])
        return sinNumeral
    } else {
        let numeral = s[0] / s[1]
        numeral > 0 ? numeral = Math.floor(numeral) : numeral = Math.ceil(numeral)
        let numeros = simplificarFraccion(modulo, s[1])
        numeros = numeros.split('/').map(a => {
            return +a < 0 ? a * -1 : +a
        }).join('/')
        return `${numeral} ${numeros}`
    }
}

function simplificarFraccion(modulo, divisor) {
    let signo = modulo / divisor;
    if (modulo < 0) modulo *= -1
    if (divisor < 0) divisor *= -1
    let act = 2;
    while (act <= divisor / 2) {
        if (modulo % act == 0 && divisor % act == 0) {
            modulo /= act;
            divisor /= act;
            act = 1
        }
        act++
    }
    return signo > 0 ? `${modulo}/${divisor}` : `-${modulo}/${divisor}`
}

console.log(convertirFraccion('-98/-91'));
console.log(convertirFraccion('-3/-7'));
console.log(convertirFraccion('4/12'));
console.log(convertirFraccion('89/-12'));
console.log(convertirFraccion('0/-12'));
console.log(convertirFraccion('33/11'));
console.log(convertirFraccion('33/0'));
```